# Problem with UnitConvert with a list

Tags: list-manipulation, units

I'm studying this part of the course units convert

I have two list 
the first: is in Megaparsec and I need to transform it to kilometers

```
r = {650, 1800, 1300, 300, 800, 700, 400, 600, 290, 600, 940, 810,600, 730, 800, 800, 580, 1100, 1140, 900, 650}
```

and the second one, this is in kilometer/seconds

```
v = {1.52, 3.45, 2.37, 0.62, 1.16, 1.42, 0.67, 1.24, 0.79, 1.0, 1.74,1.49, 1.1, 1.27, 1.53, 1.79, 1.2, 2.35, 2.23, 2.06, 1.73}
```

I need to transform it to meters/seconds

Thank in advance, and sorry for my english isn't good

edit:

this is an example of the mathematica page, why I can not see the result correctly?

[image]

Comment: Your example works fine for me. What version of Mathematica/WL are you running?

Comment: `Map[UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
   "Meters"/"Seconds"] &, v]`